# list all the files that dont match pattern in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i have to search the files that don't have pattern:-

`*abc*.txt and *xyz*.txt`

Please suggest a way to list all the files which don't have the above patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution simple grep is working for me

```
ls | grep -v "abc" | grep -v "xyz"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an extended glob, such as the following:

```
!(*@(abc|xyz)*.txt)
```

In ksh, this works by default, whereas in bash you need to first enable a shell option:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

`!` negates the match and `@` matches any of the pipe-separated patterns.

This pattern expands to the list of files that don't match `*abc*.txt` or `*xyz*.txt`, so you can pass it to another command to see the result, e.g. `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' !(*@(abc|xyz)*.txt)
```

Comment: can you please share the command i am not familiar with extended glob

Comment: It's not a command, it's just a fancy glob that expands to the list of files. I added an example anyway.

Comment: i am getting error like:- `bash: !: event not found`

Comment: `!(*@(abc|xyz)*.txt)` -- This is called a subpattern in ksh.. Use ksh to execute it..

Comment: @Tanmay you're clearly using bash if you get that error

Comment: @TomFenech can you please suggest for bash ?

Comment: @TomFenech when i am using it in script it is trowing error like `test.sh: shopt: not found` but when i am executing without script it is running fine

Comment: Probably because when you run the script you're using a different shell to your interactive one. If you have `#!/bin/ksh` at the top of the script and run it like `./script.sh` (or `ksh script.sh`) then you don't need the `shopt` line. In bash, you do.

Answer (score 2):

With `find` command:

```
find -type f ! \( -name '*abc*.txt' -o -name '*xyz*.txt' \)
```

Comment: i got error   `find: illegal option -- t
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list`

Comment: @TanmayDutta Some implementations of `find` allow you to omit the path(s) in which to search, defaulting to `.`. Yours apparently does not; try `find . -type f ...`.

Comment: what does -o mean!? what is this \( \) notation? on what situation can I use it? for what other commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--hide=PATTERN` option with ls. In your case it would be

```
ls --hide="*abc*.txt" --hide="*xyz*.txt"
```

Comment: which shell are you using?

Comment: I am using bash shell

Comment: It seems that something is broken with your shell, you get `illegal option --` every time you enter a command with an option. Which OS are you using? Any special bash config?

Comment: @piarston `--hide` is a non-standard option to `ls` so it's perfectly reasonable to expect that it doesn't exist on some systems.

Comment: @TomFenech I feared something like this, that's why I asked about the OS. From `man ls` I find no mention on which options are standard or not. Do you have a simple way to get this information or is it just experience?

Comment: The standard ones can be found by searching "opengroup ls", also works for other commands.